# Kendo Upload to Folder and URL to method in WCF Service

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, kendo-ui, ashx

Using Kendo Upload, I need to be able to send an attachment on upload to a folder location as well as post to a URL with extra parameters to send the files to a C# web method in a web service where I then perform the code that saves the files to the server.

The upload widget is being used on a create in a Kendo Grid. I am also going to need to find an id that is created server side to use as a parameter in the ashx handler and the wcf method url for the upload. Right now I am hard coding the id.

Code below:

```
                 $('#files').kendoUpload({
                async: {
                    autoUpload: false,
                    saveUrl: "save"
                },
                multiple: true,
                complete: function onComplete(e) {
                    $.map(e.files, function (file) {
                        var info = file.name;
                        e.sender.options.async.saveUrl = attachURL + "&changeControlRequestID=" + 148 + "&changeControlRequestPendingID=" + pendingId + "&directoryName=\\sat1mvdwb022.NAOTEST.G.LAB.GMACFS.COM\BSMShare\BSM\ChangeControl" + "&fileName=" + info;
                    });
                },
                upload: function onUpload(e) {
                    $.map(e.files, function (file) {
                        var info = file.name;
                        e.sender.options.async.saveUrl = "ChangeControlHandler.ashx?upload=true";
                    });
                }                     
            });
```

The first async saveUrl is linked to an ashx file. Code below :

```
public class ChangeControlHandler : IHttpHandler {

 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    int ccrID = 146;
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection fileCollection = context.Request.Files;
        if (fileCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFile filePath = fileCollection[0];

            string savepath = "filepath";
            string name = filePath.FileName.Remove(filePath.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            string fileName = ccrID.ToString() + "_" + name.Remove(0, name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1)
                   + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            string fileExt = fileName.Remove(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
            filePath.SaveAs(savepath + fileName + fileExt);
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}

 public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
 }

}
```

The file is being uploaded to the folder but it breaks with this error causing the upload to fail. [Jquery error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQm5E.png)

Comment: Where does it not work? Does the flow make it into your http handler with correct file info? Does the http handler properly call out to your service?

Comment: Also, that post is async to your handler so you might end up calling your wcf service before the file has finished uploading. If you are going to make both calls in the client app then make sure your save file function is synchronous, or use onComplete() instead of onUpload() as onUpload() is probably called when the upload has triggered and not when the upload has completed.

Comment: I've add an onComplete function which holds the url for the wcf method and its hitting the onUpload with the handler and successfully adding the files to the folder but it's breaking before it hits the onComplete. Giving me a jquery error about length.

Comment: @KVM - It would be most useful if you posted the error about length.

Comment: @RossBush I updated the original question with an image of the error